# ARCore record/replay system

Tags: android, arcore

I'm looking a way to record and replay ARCore session - video and all sensors that ARCore is using. I need something that is already available for ARKit: https://github.com/ittybittyapps/ARRecorder. Is this achievable for ARCore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARCore 1.21 introduced Recording and Playback capabilities.

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/recording-and-playback

From their release notes:

> Added Recording and Playback of ARCore datasets. The Recording feature
> lets the app capture the data required to replay the AR session.

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases/tag/v1.21.0

Comment: https://github.com/ittybittyapps/ARRecorder is broken for iOS 14 and above and there is currently no update